# Async function with arguments in child process

Tags: node.js, async-await, child-process

I'm trying to run an asynchronous function with 1 argument in a node.js child process. The function is asynchronous but I don't want to await it. I just want that function to be executed in the child process so that it can do the calculation stuff. The calculation is heavy therefore when I run it normally, It hangs my server and do not entertain any api calls during the calculation.

I tried the following code:

```
const spawn = require('await-spawn')
const { _id } = req.user;
const main = async () => {
  try {
    const bl = await spawn('node', [testUserController.refreshAllTestUsers(_id)])
    console.log(bl.toString())
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.stderr.toString())
  }
}

main()
```

but it is showing me this error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'D:\My Work[object Promise]'

Comment: `await spawn('node', [await testUserController.refreshAllTestUsers(_id)])`

Comment: Well, if you need to calculate the arguments for the `spawn` you will have to wait that promise, even if you don't want to ... If you want to do the calculations in the child process, rewrite the script you are calling with `node` to do these calculations